# How would the universe be different if gravity decreased as $d$ rather than $d^2$?

Tags: newtonian-gravity

If the law of gravitation was proportional to $\frac{Mm}{d}$ rather than $\frac{Mm}{d^2}$ (and everything else was kept the same), how would the Universe be different ? Would stars have been able to form ?

Comment: you can't keep $G$ the same, the units are wrong.

Comment: Welcome to Physics SE! its an interesting question but unfortunately a little bit off topic as it doesn't fall under "main stream physics"

Comment: There are no closed orbits for such a force, which is pretty important

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because an open-ended, hypothetical question: “What if ______ happened?” [that is explicitly off-topic](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: You need two spatial dimensions in order to have Gravity fall off as the inverse of the distance instead of the distance squared using Newtonian Physics.  The problem is that in GR in the case of two spatial dimensions spacetime will be geometrically flat outside of any uncharged non spinning mass.

Comment: Gravitation would be a 1/r force in two spatial dimensions. This question may be of some relevance with dark matter I think. The persistence of such a force due to holography, say a two dimensional gravity in a phase of sorts in three dimensional bulk, might have some relevance to the DM issue.

Answer (score 1):

A conclusion that I am getting with that assumption is that every object would turn into a **black hole**( I concluded this because the escape velocity that I'm getting is infinite).

Let me explain how:

In the case when gravity follows [inverse square law](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse-square_law) then escape velocity is given by $$v_{escape}=\sqrt {2G \frac {M}{R}}$$ but here it is different.

(What's coming next is from my classical perspective of escape velocity.)

> Escape velocity is the minimum speed needed for a free, non-propelled object to escape from the gravitational influence of a massive body.

Therefore minimum velocity would be required for the case of zero kinetic energy near infinity.

$$\Rightarrow \frac{1}{2} mv_{escape}^2 = \int_R^{\infty} G \frac {Mm}{R} dR $$
$$ \Rightarrow v_{escape}^2 = GM \ln \frac {\infty}{R}$$
$$\Rightarrow v_{escape} = \infty$$

This means that even the particles traveling at the speed of light cannot escape the gravitational influence of any object .

Answer (score 0):

A related theorem is [Bertrand's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_theorem) (just found out that this stuff has name), which states that periodic orbits can only exist in case of inverse square force potentials (such as gravity) and harmonic potential. Every other case has no stable orbits.

Comment: Closed and stable orbits aren't the same thing - there are stable orbits for lots of potentials, they just aren't ellipses.